# Difference between A subclassOf B, A subclassOf C and A subclass of intrsection B and C

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

What is the difference between stating:

```
a rdfs:subclassOf b.
a rdfs:subclassOf c.
```

and

```
a rdfs:subclass [ owl:intersectionOf ( b c)] .
```

In the first example, a inherties "class descriptions" of b as well as /additionally of c. And what is the difference to the second examples? What would be the difference if I replace subclassOf with owl:equivalentTo?

Comment: It's the same for `rdfs:subClassOf`. For `owl:equivalentTo` it's clearly different.

Answer (score 2):

The statements

```
a rdfs:subclassOf b.
a rdfs:subclassOf c.
```

are equivalent to

```
a rdfs:subclass [ owl:intersectionOf ( b c)] .
```

The effect of stating

```
a owl:equivalentTo b.
a owl:equivalentTo c.
```

is that `a` is equivalent to `b` and `a` is equivalent to `c`, which means `b` is equivalent to `c`.

The effect of stating

```
a owl:equivalent [ owl:intersectionOf ( b c)] .
```

is that `a` is equivalent to the intersection of `b` and `c`.